# React Leaflet - Extra Markers Plugin is not showing markers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Encountering an issue where the extra markers plugin is only displaying the icon. There is a very similar post to this but in Angular. My console shows no error as well. Someone who encountered this issue before (I wanted to reply to the similar post but I dont have enough reputation points to comment)

Link to similar post [Angular + Leaflet + Leaflet Extra Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873516/angular-leaflet-leaflet-extra-markers)

I have installed react-leaflet properly along with the plugin. I have also included the Font Awesome CDN's as the plugin page here required: https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-extra-markers

[image: Only icon showing]

Comment: Hi, have you solved problem? Regards, Mik.

Comment: Hey, i am not working on the project now, but i wasnt able to get it working in the end and just used the default markers instead of custom ones