# Leaflet Extra Markers: marker not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am working on a small demonstration of utilizing the Leaflet.JS Map Plugin and can't seem to display a marker using the Leaflet.Extra-Markers plugin. I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873516/angular-leaflet-leaflet-extra-markers) but they're using Angular where they downloaded the project using NPM which is what I don't want to do.

Here is the code for the Extra-Markers in the header on my index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome/5.12.0/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/leaflet.extra-markers.min.css">
<script src="libs/leaflet.extra-markers.min.js"></script>
```

It's just your standard HTML, CSS and JS file structure where I separated the Style and Scripts in a 'layout' and 'libs' folder with the 'img' file at the root where the index.html file is.
I'm already using a Marker Cluster plugin to display some Airport Locations but that shouldn't conflict with it right?
I'm using the demo code in the [documentation](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers) and this is all that comes up:

[image: screenshot]

Here is that code:

```
var redMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
    icon: 'fa-coffee',
    markerColor: 'red',
    shape: 'square',
    prefix: 'fa'
    });

    L.marker([51.941196,4.512291], {icon: redMarker}).addTo(map);
```

I expected the marker to display at the desired location that utilizes the 'fa-coffee' icon provided by the fontawesome library through Leaflet Extra Markers.

Comment: provide a link to debug. It's seems like there is only the shadow of the marker which indicates that it fails to load fontawesome. Do you have fontawesome integrated in your site?

Comment: Yes, the link I put in the header seems to work when I use a fontawesome icon like '<i class="fa-solid fa-plane"></i>' and it does appear in the page